# What writing style/guide says to emphasize (using a bold font) topic sentences?

Tags: discussion

[See this webpage/demo](http://tangledindesign.com/demos/type-pseudo-elements/index.html).
I've seen this "technique"(?) being applied both in print and online.
I want to know if there's a specific style or guide that recommends it, or if it's just common practice.

---

- [Emphasis (typography) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_(typography))

  - It mentions that **boldface** is one of the methods to add emphasis. Nothing about what parts should be emphasized.
- [A Guide to Using Bold Fonts Effectively in Page Layout](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-bold-type-effectively-1074100)

  - "In a print context, follow these best-practice ideas"
  - It doesn't talk about topic sentences specifically and does not mention who has set/recommended these "best practices".
- [Using first-line and first-letter to draw users into your copy - Tangled in Design](http://tangledindesign.com/using-first-line-and-first-letter-to-draw-people-into-your-copy/)

  - Simply suggest emphasizing the first *line* (as opposed to sentence) of each section.
- APA Style: [Font](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/paper-format/font) and [Accessible typography](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/paper-format/accessibility/typography)

  - No mention of boldface or emphasis.

Also checked (among others):

- [Paragraph Structure - Writing strong paragraphs - LibGuides at University of Newcastle Library](https://libguides.newcastle.edu.au/writing-paragraphs/structure)
- [Paragraphs & Topic Sentences: Writing Guides: Writing Tutorial Services: Indiana University Bloomington](https://wts.indiana.edu/writing-guides/paragraphs-and-topic-sentences.html)

Comment: "Nothing about what parts should be emphasized." Obviously, you emphasise the words you want to **stand out**.

Comment: [Name for making the first few words in a chapter small caps?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/411267/name-for-making-the-first-few-words-in-a-chapter-small-caps)

Comment: What makes you think this is recommended in a style guide? Have you seen it in one that you now forget, because this might help us identify it. Note that the example you post bolds the first line, not the topic sentence.

Answer (score 0):

TinfoilHat [identified](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14964/what-writing-style-guide-says-to-emphasize-using-a-bold-font-topic-sentences#comment60079_14964) [a main-site question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/411267/name-for-making-the-first-few-words-in-a-chapter-small-caps) about capitalising the first few words in a sentence, and although that asked for the name of the *technique,* one answer identified a principal proponent as Robert Bringhurst, in his seminal [*Elements of Typographic Style*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elements_of_typographic_style).

The [answer there](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/411323/18696) quoted Bringhurst:

> It is common practice to set the first word or phrase after the versal in caps, small caps, or boldface, as a bridge between versal and normal text.

and also included an image of the examples from *Elements*.

A linked answer on [GraphicDesign.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/35128/4215) shows a bit of history; the practice is actually centuries-old.